# SQL Syntax NOT IN for Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The Google SQL syntax guide found here
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference
does not seem to address use of the NOT IN terminology.

I get the error

```
Query Failed
Error: Encountered "" at line 0, column 0. Was expecting one of:
```

(and then Google lists nothing after the words 'one of')

when my query is

```
SELECT ageinmonths,amountborrowed,borrowerrate,creationdate,creditgrade,
       debttoincomeratio,groupkey,key,lenderrate,listingkey,modifieddata,
       originationdate,prosperrating,status,term
FROM prosperloans1.loans2 as big,
     prosperloans1.dupelistingkeysinloans2 as small
WHERE big.listingkey NOT IN small.listingkey
```

the table 'small' has 14 rows.  The table big has 57K rows.

Any ideas?
Not sure if Google SQL supports NOT IN.

Thanks
Shawn

Comment: don't you need parenthesis when you use in or not in?
e.g.  select * from dual where id not in (1, 2, 3)

Comment: this seemed to work: SELECT ageinmonths,amountborrowed,borrowerrate,creationdate,creditgrade,debttoincomeratio,groupkey,key,lenderrate,listingkey,modifieddata,originationdate,prosperrating,status,term
FROM prosperloans1.loans2
WHERE listingkey 
NOT IN (SELECT listingkey from prosperloans1.dupelistingkeysinloans2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Semijoins and antijoins use the following syntax:
`SELECT field
FROM table
WHERE field [NOT] IN (SELECT other_field FROM other_table WHERE foo = 'bar')`

So your updated query with the subselect is the correct version.

Comment: It can also be useful to run queries that do NOT match lists of strings, such as: SELECT word, COUNT(*) as word_count from publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE word NOT IN ('the', 'and', 'i', 'to', 'of', 'a') GROUP BY word ORDER BY word_count DESC IGNORE CASE;

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it was okay to use **WHERE field [NOT] IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(other_field) FROM other_table)** or **WHERE field [NOT] IN (SELECT other_field FROM other_table)**.  This helped me, but not sure why GROUP_CONCAT doesn't work.

Comment: How are you using GROUP_CONCAT? This will just generate a comma-separated string value with the concatenated group values. Do you expect this to match the field in the outer query? GROUP_CONCAT may concatenate results in arbitrary order, which may be a reason why you wouldn't get expected match.